# GDAL Dockerfile image for lambda Python function causes gdal_translate error: /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: gdal, docker, lambda

Via the work of perrygeo (https://www.perrygeo.com/running-python-with-compiled-code-on-aws-lambda.html) and then the GDAL layer work from https://github.com/lambgeo/geo-layer, I was able to include GDAL binary and python layers for a lambda function that processes GRIB data for a webpage.  Recently, python 3.7 runtime became unsupported in AWS lambda and I had to upgrade those layers to a supported python runtime.  I attempted to include updated versions of the layers but ran into the 250MB total limit for lambda functions.  Based on other responses from gis.stackexchange and stackoverflow, the next best thing would be to build the GDAL binaries and python bindings via docker, include the lambda function python code, push the resulting image to the Elastic Container Registry (ECR), and create my lambda function from that image.  However, the published GDAL dockerfiles aren't really meant to be part of a lambda function but used for installing GDAL on one's system.  From the lambgeo/docker-lambda README file (https://github.com/lambgeo/docker-lambda/pkgs/container/lambda-gdal) as well as using the alpine-normal GDAL Dockerfile with some modification during the final docker COPY section (https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/docker/alpine-normal/Dockerfile), I was able to successfully build an image and test the lambda function created from the image.  I modified the end of that Dockerfile like so:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.10 as lbuilder

ENV LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT=/var/task
ENV PACKAGE_PREFIX=opt

# Order layers starting with less frequently varying ones
COPY --from=builder  /build_thirdparty/usr/ /${PACKAGE_PREFIX}/

COPY --from=builder  /build_projgrids/usr/ /${PACKAGE_PREFIX}/

COPY --from=builder  /build_spatialite/usr/ /${PACKAGE_PREFIX}/

COPY --from=builder  /build_proj/usr/share/proj/ /${PACKAGE_PREFIX}/share/proj/
COPY --from=builder  /build_proj/usr/include/ /${PACKAGE_PREFIX}/include/
COPY --from=builder  /build_proj/usr/bin/ /${PACKAGE_PREFIX}/bin/
COPY --from=builder  /build_proj/usr/lib/ /${PACKAGE_PREFIX}/lib/

COPY --from=builder  /build/usr/share/gdal/ /${PACKAGE_PREFIX}/share/gdal/
COPY --from=builder  /build/usr/include/ /${PACKAGE_PREFIX}/include/
COPY --from=builder  /build_gdal_python/usr/ /${PACKAGE_PREFIX}/python/
COPY --from=builder  /build_gdal_version_changing/usr/ /${PACKAGE_PREFIX}/
```

My lambda function code is copied to the docker image after that.

It looked like from a listing of the directories I copied to using the directories in the Dockerfile that was successful.  However, when I ran gdal_translate, I got the following error:

```
Error:b'/bin/sh: /opt/bin/gdal_translate: /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory\n'
```

I've searched for the error and it looks like there may be some sort of glibc issue.  Perhaps I need to install something else in the Dockerfile or something else should be in the Dockerfile steps?  My docker command to build is

```
docker build -t myimagetag .
```

I was also trying to specify the platform as that was recommended in the lambda docs when building containers:

```
docker build --platform linux/amd64 -t myimagetag .
```

But the error was originally with that as well. I also just built the image using an unchanged version of the dockerfile where the last COPY commands copy to the /usr/ directory and its subdirectories.  Error was still there upon running the lambda function.

I stored the docker build output in a file and saw lines similar to this:

```
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld
#12 10.97 checking if the linker (/usr/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
```

So, if the linker is listed here, unsure why something related isn't being found when gdal_translate is called.

There was also a note here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55532716/running-a-containers-elf-file-without-container about musl is used to compile portable static binaries and that something went wrong with the compilation of the program trying to run.

The reason I'm attempting to do this is that my development group would not like to rely on the lambgeo docker files, especially since it appears that the Python bindings for GDAL 3.8 don't appear to be available as they were previously.  So, whenever python reaches EOL on AWS, we'd just have to rebuild the image with the needed python version from GDAL dockerfiles instead.  That along with getting around the current 250MB lambda layers size limit via creating a function via the Docker image.  That solution allows up to 10GB presently.

Very new at working with Docker and Dockerfiles.

Suggestions?